# how to do set value from a p tag to react state

Tags: reactjs

How do i set a state from a dynamically created p tag? The value i am trying to get is a mongodb id which is in the singleClass.id.How would i be able to set that id value as state for each iteration.So when button is clicked it goes to registerClass iam getting courseID.I used handleCourse but its not working for me please help.

```
handleCourse = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      courseID: e.target.value
    });
  };
<ul className="collection with-header" key={singleClass.id}>
        <li className="collection-item">
          <div>
            <p value={this.state.courseID} onChange={this.handleCourse}>
              {singleClass.courseID}
            </p>
            <span>{singleClass.courseName}</span>
            <div className="secondary-content">
              <button
                style={btnColor}
                onClick={this.registerClass}
                className="btn btn-flat"
                type="button"
              >
                Enroll
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: why you have ```onChange``` and ```value``` attribute on a ```<p>``` tag? Why not using ```<input type="text" ...``` ?

Comment: becuase i am not getting an input from user.I am just getting id from a mongodb _id.each element will have differen id .When the user clicks button i want to get that specific id

Comment: alright but onChange is an attribute that's supposed to be added to an input field, it invokes whenever you edit the input field. ```<p>``` tag is not editable, and shouldn't be. So you can't invoke the ```onChange``` attribute. That's why it won't work as expected.